# Can I install the ordinary php and php-cli on the same machine?

Tags: package-management, php, php-cli

I want to install `php5` on my machine and also `php5-cli`. I want to first install the ordinary `php5` package and then `php5-cli`.

Are there likely to be any conflicts if I do this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

followed by this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there should be no problems at all. If there are, they are unexpected bugs. In fact, you can install both at once:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cli
```

In general, Debian maintainers (and downstream, Ubuntu maintainers) work hard to make sure packages work well with each other. If they do not, they are marked as being in conflict with each other, and `apt-get` will not let you install both.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use php 5.4 and the interactive cli (*php -a*), don't forget to add the `php5-readline` package as well.